# How to animate height change on Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970250/animate-height-change-on-bootstraps-carousel) question. The proposed solution [doesn't work](http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/EJgaL) for Bootstrap 3 unfortunately (although it [does](http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/pGsui) for bs 2.3.1). So how would I do it there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's possible to fix this with a simple JavaScript-Snippet:

```
function bsCarouselAnimHeight()
{
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    }).on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e)
    {
        var nextH = $(e.relatedTarget).height();
        $(this).find('.active.item').parent().animate({ height: nextH }, 500);
    });
}
```