# Animate height change on Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

On researching the question "How to animate height change on Bootstrap 3 Carousel" I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639550/how-to-animate-height-change-on-bootstrap-3-carousel), however it doesn't have any effects on my bootstrap carousel. I can't comment yet and ask for clarification there, therefore a new Question.

The solution suggested there is

```
function bsCarouselAnimHeight()
{
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
}).on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e)
{
    var nextH = $(e.relatedTarget).height();
    $(this).find('.active.item').parent().animate({ height: nextH }, 500);
});
}
```

But as I said, without any effect. Maybe I should modify any selectors in the Javascript in my case?

## Update:

I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psteinweber/4HDBe/) so it's actually showing the problem.

All ideas are appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is fine. You're just not calling `function bsCarouselAnimHeight()` anywhere so none of it is firing.

You can either take it out of the function declaration

http://jsfiddle.net/4HDBe/3/

or call the function at some point.

http://jsfiddle.net/4HDBe/4/