# When div is getting more content let it get larger smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am making a menu card for a website.

I did make a slider so the menu card does have different categorys, but some categorys has more content than other ones.

So it makes the div bigger but it makes the div bigger very roughly. 
You can take a live look at this page: http://toontjeindestad.coersonline.nl/ and then scroll down to the menu with the arrows.

I tried giving the div a transition but that doesnt work either.

Here is my HTML code for the slider / menu.

```
<div id="text-carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides --> 
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div class="repsonsivecontent" style="position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
                    <?php if( have_rows('voorgerechten') ): ?>

                        <?php while( have_rows('voorgerechten') ): the_row(); 

                            // vars
                            $gerechtvoorgerecht = get_sub_field('gerecht');
                            $prijsvoorgerecht = get_sub_field('prijs');
                            $omschrijvingvoorgerecht = get_sub_field('omschrijving');

                            ?>
                            <div id="margin" style="width: 300px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; position: relative;">
                                <h3 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 0px;"><?php echo $gerechtvoorgerecht?></h3><br>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><i><?php echo $omschrijvingvoorgerecht?></i></p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i>&euro; <?php echo $prijsvoorgerecht?></i></p><br>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div class="repsonsivecontent" style="position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
                    <?php if( have_rows('vleesgerechten') ): ?>

                        <?php while( have_rows('vleesgerechten') ): the_row(); 

                            // vars
                            $gerechtvleesgerecht = get_sub_field('gerecht');
                            $prijsvleesgerecht = get_sub_field('prijs');
                            $omschrijvingvleesgerecht = get_sub_field('omschrijving');

                            ?>
                            <div id="margin" style="width: 300px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; position: relative;">
                                <h3 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 0px;"><?php echo $gerechtvleesgerecht?></h3><br>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><i><?php echo $omschrijvingvleesgerecht?></i></p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i>&euro; <?php echo $prijsvleesgerecht?></i></p><br>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-id="1">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div class="repsonsivecontent" style="position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
                    <?php if( have_rows('visgerechten') ): ?>

                        <?php while( have_rows('visgerechten') ): the_row(); 

                            // vars
                            $gerechtvisgerecht = get_sub_field('gerecht');
                            $prijsvisgerecht = get_sub_field('prijs');
                            $omschrijvingvisgerecht = get_sub_field('omschrijving');

                            ?>
                            <div id="margin" style="width: 300px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; position: relative;">
                                <h3 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 0px;"><?php echo $gerechtvisgerecht?></h3><br>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><i><?php echo $omschrijvingvisgerecht?></i></p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i>&euro; <?php echo $prijsvisgerecht?></i></p><br>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div class="repsonsivecontent" style="position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
                    <?php if( have_rows('soepen') ): ?>

                        <?php while( have_rows('soepen') ): the_row(); 

                            // vars
                            $gerechtsoep = get_sub_field('gerecht');
                            $prijssoep = get_sub_field('prijs');
                            $omschrijvingsoep = get_sub_field('omschrijving');

                            ?>
                            <div id="margin" style="width: 300px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; position: relative;">
                                <h3 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 0px;"><?php echo $gerechtsoep?></h3><br>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><i><?php echo $omschrijvingsoep?></i></p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i>&euro; <?php echo $prijssoep?></i></p><br>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div class="repsonsivecontent" style="position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">
                    <?php if( have_rows('nagerechten') ): ?>

                        <?php while( have_rows('nagerechten') ): the_row(); 

                            // vars
                            $gerechtnagerecht = get_sub_field('gerecht');
                            $prijsnagerecht = get_sub_field('prijs');
                            $omschrijvingnagerecht = get_sub_field('omschrijving');

                            ?>
                            <div id="margin" style="width: 300px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; position: relative;">
                                <h3 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 0px;"><?php echo $gerechtnagerecht?></h3><br>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><i><?php echo $omschrijvingnagerecht?></i></p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i>&euro; <?php echo $prijsnagerecht?></i></p><br>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div class="repsonsivecontent" style="position: relative; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">   
                    <?php if( have_rows('koffieenlekkers') ): ?>

                        <?php while( have_rows('koffieenlekkers') ): the_row(); 

                            // vars
                            $gerechtkoffieenlekkers = get_sub_field('gerecht');
                            $prijskoffieenlekkers = get_sub_field('prijs');
                            $omschrijvingkoffieenlekkers = get_sub_field('omschrijving');

                            ?>
                            <div id="margin" style="width: 300px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px; position: relative;">
                                <h3 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 0px;"><?php echo $gerechtkoffieenlekkers?></h3><br>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 0px;"><i><?php echo $omschrijvingkoffieenlekkers?></i></p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-family: Merriweather; color:white; font-size: 16px;"><i>&euro; <?php echo $prijskoffieenlekkers?></i></p><br>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#text-carousel" data-slide="prev" onclick="">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#text-carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>     
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried this awesome css library? [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `boostrap carousal` try to add the below code in your page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
     interval: 5000
  }).on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
     var nextH = $(e.relatedTarget).height();
     $(this).find('.active').parent().animate({ height: nextH }, 500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi use this js code for slider height smoothness** 
you can see ans here [Animate height change on Bootstrap 3 Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564447/animate-height-change-on-bootstrap-3-carousel)

```
 $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000
    }).on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var nextH = $(e.relatedTarget).height();
        console.log(nextH)
        console.log( $(this).find('.active.item').parent() )
        $(this).find('.active.item').parent().animate({
            height: nextH
        }, 500);
    });
```